# Order stacked barplot by total number

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was trying to order the bars in descending order (all the segments together) using reorder(). However, this seems not to work. How can I do this?

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Sample data frame
df <- data.frame(var = sample(paste0("x", 1:10), size = 100, replace = TRUE),
                 var2 = sample(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), size = 100, replace = TRUE))

# Stacked barplot
df %>% group_by(var) %>%
  count(var2) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(var, n, fun = "sum"), y = n, fill = var2)) +  
    geom_col()
```

Comment: Try `reorder(var, n, FUN = "sum")` with a capital letter FUN

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use `add_count` together with fct_infreq():

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  add_count(var) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = fct_infreq(var), y = n, fill = var2)) +  
  geom_col()
```

[image]

Comment: TarJae, this is very nice - would you mind adding this to the linked duplicate thread and ping me please

Comment: Do you mean as an answer to <Order Stacked Bar Graph by sum / total of all subgroups>?

Answer (score 2):

It works if you use `forcats::fct_reorder` (part of the tidyverse) rather than `reorder`...

```
df %>% group_by(var) %>%
  count(var2) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = fct_reorder(var, n, .fun = sum), y = n, fill = var2)) +  
  geom_col()
```